# Button location: Save / Next / Cancel / Text notice

Tags: buttons, save, position

I am facing an issue in a recent project about the position of buttons.

In the UI system, we have this button group bar fixed to the bottom of page which already using in other pages.

[image]

So in the new page design, we need to place "Next" button on it. I want to place at right cause it is consistent to other pages. It is far from the "Save" button but I don't think it is necessary to place next to it.
*Auto-saving is not applicable in this page

[image]

If we leave the button next to "Save" button, it seems more easy to user. But it will be different to other pages.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In UX design (and design in general for that matter) consistency is key.

Therefore, the "Next" button should also be to the far right (as you mention other pages do that). Keep in mind that if the "Next" button was directly to the right of the "Save" button it would cause some confusion. Not only does it look like it, but it sits where the "Cancel" button is usually. Therefore if someone was to hit "Cancel" quickly (out of habit), they would accidentally go "Next" instead. If that location is a must (for whatever reason), change the styling of the "Next" button to differentiate it from the "Cancel" button (ie. orange border and text).